# Python Class instance variables printing out as tuples instead of string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating the following `class` within python. But when I create an instance of the `class` and print out the `imdb_id` value. It prints it as a *tuple*.

What am I doing wrong? I would like it to simply print out the *string*.

```
class Movie(object):
    """ Class provides a structure to store Movie information """

    def __init__(self, imdb_id, title = None, release_year = None, rating = None, run_time = None, genre = None, director = None, actors = None, plot = None, awards = None, poster_image = None, imdb_votes = None, youtube_trailer = None):
        self.imdb_id = imdb_id,
        self.title = title,
        self.release_year = release_year
        self.rating = rating,
        self.run_time = run_time,
        self.genre = genre,
        self.director = director,
        self.actors = actors,
        self.plot = plot,
        self.awards = awards,
        self.poster_image = poster_image,
        self.imdb_votes = imdb_votes,
        self.youtube_trailer = youtube_trailer
```

Here is how I am initiating the class:

```
import media
toy_story=media.Movie("trtreter")
toy_story.imdb_id
```

Comment: You created a single element tuple by appending comma to right-hand-side of all of assignment (well, all besides `self.youtube_trailer`). Remove them and code'll work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you adding a comma at the end of most statements? That creates a tuple. Remove the trailing comma.

Really, why are you doing that?